# How do I correct my code for this program to run?

Tags: c++

You are given an m x n integer matrix with the following two properties:

Each row is sorted in non-decreasing order.
The first integer of each row is greater than the last integer of the previous row.
Given an integer target, return true if the target is in the matrix or false otherwise

```
public:
    bool searchMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int target) {
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        while(i<matrix.size() and j<matrix[0].size() ){
            if(i>=matrix.size() or j>=matrix[0].size()){
                return false;
            }
            if(matrix[i][j]==target){
                return true;
            }
            else if(matrix[i][j+1]<=target and matrix[i+1][j]>target){
                j++;
            }else if(matrix[i+1][j]<=target){
                i++;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }return false;
    }
};
```

Why is this code not working???

Comment: I do not understand the process your code is trying to work through. It might help if you can describe the algorithm you are trying to work through (doing this may help you find the issue on your own as well).

Comment: This question is not well asked. Please provide some detail to the question. Why do you think your code is not working? What have you tried so far?  To be fair, this sounds like a homework problem you had to solve, tried once and went to asking others. Moreover, providing a minimal working example could potentially mean include data to test the program + the expected output.

Comment: You forgot to mention what the code is supposed to do. Check if `target` is present in the matrix? Your code doesnt look like that. What should it do?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number `return true if the target is in the matrix or false otherwise`

Comment: you seem to make assumptions that dont hold. First line can be `1 3 4 5` and second line can be `2 101 102 103`. Now suppose target is `101` then your code will (if I understand correctly) go till end of first row then report that target was not found. You should use a debugger to see what your code does and understand why it fails

Comment: The `i+1` and `j+1` will cause out of bounds accesses when i is size -1 or j is size -1

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this up into steps.

We know the rows are sorted, so we can first find the row that contains the item. I will also use for loops instead of while loops since a for loop better models what we are doing.

```
bool searchMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int target) {
    // use descriptive variables names to make the code easier to understand
    size_t rowCount = matrix.size();
    if (rowCount == 0) return false;
    size_t colCount = matrix[0].size();

    for (size_t r = 0; r < rowCount; r++) {
        // We need to check if the target could be in this row.
        // So there are three cases:

        // 1. Target is less than all items in this row
        if (target < matrix[r][0]) return false;

        // 2. Target is greater than all items in this row
        if (target > matrix[r][colCount - 1]) continue;

        // 3. Target is within this row if present
        // TODO
    }
}
```

At this point, we know what row it is in and we just have to search that row. This seems like a school homework problem and I don't want to just give you the whole answer, so hopefully you can fill in the rest from here.

One thing I would add is that we can make things cleaner by using "range based for loops" and some helpers methods on std::vector to do away with indexing:

```
bool searchMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int target) {
    for (const auto& row : matrix) {
        // We need to check if the target could be in this row.
        // So there are three cases:

        // 1. Target is less than all items in this row
        if (target < row.front()) return false;
        
        // 2. Target is greater than all items in this row
        if (target > row.back()) continue;
        
        // 3. Target is within this row if present
        // TODO (can used a range based for loop for this as well)
    }

    return false;
}
```